# URL rewriting to another sub domain

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to create an URL Rewrite rule to send :

> www.mycompany.com/file.aspx?someQueryString
>   or
>   www.mycompany.com/fileXYZ.aspx?someQueryString

to

> www.subdomain.mycompany.com/file.aspx?someQueryString
>   or
>   www.subdomain.mycompany.com/fileXYZ.aspx?someQueryString

I wrote this rule:

`<rule name="MyPageRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)(file[a-zA-Z]*\.aspx)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://subdomain.mycompany.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>`

The match expression seems to work, however the destination doesn't?  What is wrong?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Lex Li, I did many tests with the test aspx file you provided and found a rule that works:

```
<rule name="MyPageRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)(file[a-zA-Z]*\.aspx)" />
   <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="http://subdomain.mycompany.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true"/> 
</rule>
```